# Set tappable focus on button element of UIAlertView during VoiceOver - UIAccessibility

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I intend to set accessibility focus (tappable focus) using `UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification` on the button element of a `UIAlertView`. In order to hold a reference to the button, it was implemented thus in the code below:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] init] autorelease];
alert.delegate = self;
[alert setTitle:@"Title"];
[alert setMessage:@"Message"];

[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Button"];
UIButton *yesButton = [alert.subviews lastObject];
[yesButton setHidden:NO];

myButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] autorelease];
[myButton retain];
[alert addSubview:myButton];
[alert show];

[myButton setAccessibilityLabel:@"This is my button"];
[myButton setFrame:yesButton.frame];

[alert show];
```

If VoiceOver is running, I want the tappable focus to be on the button and not the title element. So i do this when the alert view is shown:

```
if(UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning()){
    UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification, myButton);
}
```

However, the accessibility label of the button is read out by VoiceOver ("this is my button"), but the tappable focus is not set on the button but remains on the title element of the `UIAlertView`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to fight VoiceOver? Users are able to navigate very swiftly, in part due to the consistency with which VoiceOver traverses user interfaces. Try not to get in their way by altering defaults.

That said, you may be able to override default VoiceOver focus by posting the layout change notification *after* the alert view appears. Try doing so from `-didPresentAlertView:` of your [UIAlertViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/). You may also need to wait a short time before posting the notification to ensure that the view is done appearing and that VoiceOver has noticed. `dispatch_async()` is excellent for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What you suggested is valid and i already implemented     `[self performSelector:@selector(readOutEmergencyCallAnnouncement) withObject:self afterDelay:4.0f];` to run the `UIAccessibilityPostNotification` which would essentially do the same as the `dispatch_async()`. Anyway, it still doesn't set the "tappable" focus. Like you said, i might have to get back to the client not to break iOS convention